# Faster Loops in R

Tags: r

I am trying to minimize the amount of time it takes for my program to run. One thing I know from programming in other languages is that some loops run slower than others. Right now I am using a repeat loop and I was wondering if there is a faster option.

```
FindPnL <- function(StockData, MA1, MA2, SL, LS, Day, Buy, Sell){

PnL <- 0
  MA1Value <- moving_avg(StockData, MA1, Day)
  MA2Value <- moving_avg(StockData, MA2, Day)
  repeat{
    MA1Prev <- MA1Value
    MA2Prev <- MA2Value
    Day <- Day + 1
    if(Day>7890){ #Pending length technique
      break
    }
    MA1Value <- moving_avg(StockData, MA1, Day)
    MA2Value <- moving_avg(StockData, MA2, Day)
    results <- CheckCross(MA1Prev, MA2Prev, MA1Value, MA2Value)
    Buy <- CheckCross(MA1Prev, MA2Prev, MA1Value, MA2Value)[["a"]]
    Sell <- CheckCross(MA1Prev, MA2Prev, MA1Value, MA2Value)[["b"]]
    PnL <- Transaction(Buy, Sell, PnL, Day, SL, LS, StockData)[["a"]]
    Day <- Transaction(Buy, Sell, PnL, Day, SL, LS, StockData)[["b"]]
    Buy <- FALSE
    Sell <- FALSE
  }
  return(PnL)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the sample function

```
CheckCross <- function(...){
 Buy <- TRUE
 Sell <- FALSE
 results <- list(a = Buy, b = Sell)
 return(results)
}
```

You can replace

```
Buy <- CheckCross(MA1Prev, MA2Prev, MA1Value, MA2Value)[["a"]]
Sell <- CheckCross(MA1Prev, MA2Prev, MA1Value, MA2Value)[["b"]]
```

with

```
cc <- CheckCross(MA1Prev, MA2Prev, MA1Value, MA2Value)
Buy <- cc$a
Sell <- cc$b
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and got this error message.....Error in cc$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: You said the function returned a list. That error message implies it is not returning a list. It works in my (updated) example.